# How to enter an ellipsis (Unicode 0x2026) in a MS Teams chat?

Tags: microsoft-teams, special-characters, shortcut

In most programs you can enter the ellipsis sign (three horizontal dots …) by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>. Not in MS teams. I neither found an autocorrection to replace three normal dots automatically. And three normal dots simply do not look like an ellipses …

What is the trick?

Comment: what's the background behind this peculiar stuff?

Comment: Why peculiar? It's an every-day requirement, therefore working in almost any software I use, but not in MS teams. I don't know the background why MS did something special in teams, I just need to know how to make it work.

Comment: Not all everyday stuff needs an ellipsis. In fact, not all programs also support ellipses too, i.e. Notepad, VS code, all internet browsers with standard text boxes. I don't need that when I code. Some programs do support that, especially any rich text application like MS Word. That's the reason why I was asking, what is the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to get a an ellipse in Teams chat on Windows 10 by pressing ALT (and holding) and then 0 1 3 3 (on the numeric keypad).

[This blog](https://blog.tomayac.com/2011/09/07/generating-the-ellipsis-character-on-mac-windows-and-linux-180523/#:%7E:text=Maybe%20this%20comes%20in%20handy,Alt%20for%20all%20Mac%20newbies.) also mentions a way of changing to unicode input.

Comment: You are right, that works. Just a little bit hard to remember …

Comment: Yeah I remember about 15 years ago I switched from typsetting on Macs (which have fairly easy ways of typing special characters) to Windows. There are a whole host of alt-keypad 0169 is copyright, 0150 is en dash, 0151 is em dash, and so on. They work in almost every application I've ever used.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's not supported.

You can always submit your feedback to Microsoft Teams product team via https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/.

Comment: Thank you. I suggested it there.